# Read and print an encoded message received from server which is stored in buffer of type UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>

Tags: swift, xcode, sockets

I'm receiving a message from a local host server. The server sends me a message in `XML` format which is `UTF-8 encoded` This message is stored in a variable called buffer of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`. Now I tried to print this buffer but all it shows is 0, it works if I send a string that isn't encoded but the requirement is that the string being send is encoded in ```UTF-8``

> Here is the code I use to read the message:

```
let maxreadlength = 4096
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: maxreadlength)

while InputStream.hasBytesAvailable {
      let numberOfBytesRead = InputStream.read(buffer, maxLength: maxreadlength)

      if numberOfBytesRead < 0, let error = InputStream.streamError{
           print(error)
           break
      }
}

let output = String(cString: buffer)
print("server output is: \(output)")
```

> The XML message I receive is supposed to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Details>
 <response>
  <name>Name</name>
  <ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
 </response>
</Details>
```

Can someone help tell me what i'm doing wrong and what can I do to decode the message?

> Here's what I've tried:

`let output2 = String(describing: output.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8))`

this didn't seem to work either. I tried a few others that were similar to this but none of those seemed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the buffer simply as `[UInt8]`

```
let maxreadlength = 4096
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: maxreadlength)
```

and read the data

```
let numberOfBytesRead = InputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: maxreadlength)
```

then create the string

```
let string = String(bytes: buffer, encoding: .utf8)
```